# How to do a lot of polls at once time?

Tags: python, discord

main.py

````
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get
from config import settings



bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = settings['prefix'])


BanMember = None
BanReason = None

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("   Login as {0.user}".format(bot))
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.listening, name="*voteban"))
    
@bot.command() 
async def voteban(ctx, member : discord.Member=None, reason=None):
       if member==None or reason==None:
        message = await ctx.send("*voteban @mention <reason>")
       else:
        global BanMember, BanReason
        BanMember = member.id
        BanReason = reason
        await ctx.channel.purge(limit=1)
        message = await ctx.send(f"Ban poll:```\nUser: {member}({member.id})\nReason: {reason}```\n**✅ = Ban**", delete_after=settings['polltime'])    
        await message.add_reaction('✅')
        settings['user'] = member
        settings['msg'] = message.id
        settings['reason'] = reason
        print(f"\n   BAN Poll:\n   MOD: {ctx.author.name}\n   User: {member}\n   Reason: {reason}\n{settings['user']}|{settings['msg']}")

@bot.event
async def on_raw_reaction_add(payload):
    if payload.channel_id == settings['modchannel']:
        if payload.emoji.name == "✅":
            channel = bot.get_channel(payload.channel_id)
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)
            reaction = get(message.reactions, emoji=payload.emoji.name)
            payload.member = settings['user']
            print(f"   {reaction},{reaction.count}/4")
            if reaction and reaction.count > settings['needreactions']:
                await payload.member.ban(reason=BanReason)
                print(f"   \nUser {payload.member} was banned")


bot.run(settings['token'])
````

config.py

```
settings = {
    'token': 'TOKEN',
    'bot': 'NAME',
    'id': 123,
    'prefix': '*',
    'modchannel': 123,
    'needreactions': 3,
    'polltime': 7200,
    'user': 0, 
    'msg': 0,
    'reason': 'None'
}
```

I have studied some issues and think that this can be done with json, but do not understand how. Yeah, it feels more like a task than a question. But please tell me how to do it? At the moment, if you call *voteban when the other is not completed, the bot will forget about the old one.

Comment: "I have studied some issues and think that this can be done with json" *What* can be done with JSON? You've  presented us with code with only the sketchiest indication of what it's supposed to do. Please take a step back and explain what it is you are trying to achieve. You've presented us with code that doesn't do what you want. You need to explain what you do want and why your solution is unsatisfactory. And no, the question topic *isn't* sufficient explanation. We can't  work out your intent from code that doesn't express that intent.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.